# Display resolution setup

Tags: greeter

I'm trying to setup my display at 2560x1440 @60Hz. I can use xrandr and it all works.

I've created a script in /usr/local/bin to do this on startup but cannot get it to run prior to login screen prompt.

I've tried creating a lightdm.conf file and added

display-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/displaysetup.sh

but no luck.

Anyone able to help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You no need to run the script at startup each time you can permanently set resolution like this:

```
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1140
```

You can get list of your display by running:

```
xrandr -q
```

Just make sure the resolution you're trying to set is supported by your monitor.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what i need to do. That is what my script does, and it works on other distros. Just does not get executed with elementary when added to lightdm.conf